# get back command prompt after opening programs from terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fedora

When I launch any application from terminal, then the terminal gets locked until I close that application. What I want is just to use terminal for launching programs and then use the same terminal for other purpose without closing that application.

I googled up and found that one solution is running the process in background like

```
      gedit &
```

Is n't there any other way by which I only type "gedit" and then return to command prompt?
Because I have seen such use in fedora terminal. How is it done in fedora by default ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to do what you are asking without patching either bash or every application you wish to give this behavior to. However if you want to put a program running on a terminal into the background (as though you had run it with `&` is to switch to the terminal it is running on, press `CTRL-Z` and then type `bg`. The first thing says to suspend execution of the process and the second says to restart it in the background.

Comment: what I wanted to ask is , how we can open apps in fedora terminal in background without using '&' and not in ubuntu ??

Comment: You cannot. I tried this just a few minutes ago. With the exception of apps that implement the background functionality (such as `xdg-open`, which you might want to try out) the functionality is the same as in ubuntu. This is mostly because the behavior is specified in bash, which both distro's use the same version of.